# Undefined index: id in vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63

Tags: magento2.3, configuration

I am having this issue when I try to install the extension ...

Comment: Did you create any custom module? If so did you create system.xml? Share the code it will be helpful to identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

**This Is Error For System.xml File :-**

> Try disabling all the custom modules and check for the error. If the system doesn't throw any errors, then that means one of **system.xml**
>   file in your custom modules is causing the issue.